# Client certificate for access to imap server in gnus

Tags: gnus

We're in the process of changing mail servers. The new one will require a client certificate from our internal CA for all connections. How can I make gnus use a client certificate in the connection? I can't find any option for that in the nnimap documentation.

I tried setting it up like this:

```
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods '(
                  (nnimap "imap"
                      (nnimap-address "imap.example.com")
                      (nnimap-server-port 993)
                      (nnimap-stream ssl)
                      (nnimap-inbox "INBOX")
                      (nnimap-split-methods default)
                      )
                  ))
```

and with the authinfo entry

```
machine imap.example.com  port imaps key "~/.privat/certs/jenny.key" cert "~/.privat/certs/jenny.pem"
```

When I try to connect, I get the following errors in emacs:

```
Opening nnimap server on imap...
Opening connection to imap.example.com via tls...
auth-source-search: found 1 backends matching (:max 1 :host ("imap.example.com" "imap") :port (993 "imaps" "imap" "993" "143") :user nil :require (:user :secret) :create t)
auth-source-search: found 0 results (max 1) matching (:max 1 :host ("imap.example.com" "imap") :port (993 "imaps" "imap" "993" "143") :user nil :require (:user :secret) :create t)
auth-source-search: found 1 backends matching (:max 1 :host ("imap.example.com" "imap") :port (993 "imaps" "imap" "993" "143"))
auth-source-search: found 0 results (max 1) matching (:max 1 :host ("imap.example.com" "imap") :port (993 "imaps" "imap" "993" "143"))
auth-source-search-backend: got 1 (max 1) in netrc:~/.authnfo-test matching (:max 1 :host ("imap.example.com" "imap") :port (993 "imaps" "imap" "993" "143") :user nil :require (:user :secret) :create t)
auth-source-search: CREATED 1 results (max 1) matching (:max 1 :host ("imap.example.com" "imap") :port (993 "imaps" "imap" "993" "143") :user nil :require (:user :secret) :create t)
Opening nnimap server on imap...failed: NO (ALERT) Client didn't present valid SSL certificate
```

The mailserver also says no certificate was presented:

```
Dec 12 11:10:22 imap dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (client didn't send a cert):
```

Comment: That 'CREATED' means auth-source didn't find a match. From the debug I think that the authinfo entry needs a 'login' field as well. ('password' it should prompt for).

Comment: And if the authentication required by the server is *only* cert based, not username/password based, then I think changes would be required in nnimap.el

Answer (score 1):

I took the shortcut of using openssl for the SSL connection:

```
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods '(
                      (nnimap "post"
                          (nnimap-address "post.example.se")
                          (nnimap-server-port 993)
                          (nnimap-stream shell)
                          (nnimap-shell-program "openssl s_client -host post.example.se -port 993 -key /home/jenny/.privat/certs/jenny.key -cert /home/jenny/.privat/certs/jenny.pem -CAfile /home/jenny/.privat/certs/ExampleServerCertificateAuthority.pem")
                          (nnimap-inbox "INBOX")
                          (nnimap-split-methods default)
                          )
                      ))
```

Note that the upcoming emacs-27 has support for using `key` and `cert` specifications from `auth-source` automatically, so that the builtin GnuTLS support will work in place of the external tools.

Comment: Ugh. In theory you should be able to specify the client certificate to use via auth-source, which should then cause the default underlying `open-network-stream` to pass that to the builtin TLS functions, but I can't see an actual implementation of that in auth-source.el. Might be worth asking on emacs-devel.

Comment: I'm blind. The following type of`.authinfo` entry should work: `machine post.example.se port 993 key "~/.my_smtp_tls.key" cert "~/.my_smtp_tls.cert"`

Comment: @rpluim Thanks for the suggestion - I didn't even consider authinfo. But I didn't get it to work with authinfo; I turned on àuth-debug trivia` and I could see that it used the correct line, but the server says that no certifiate was presented. (I agree with your *ugh* about this solution, though!)

Comment: Could you update your question to show what your nnimap select method looks like now? If it's not using the builtin GNUTls things won't work.

Comment: @rpluim I've updated it now.